# Select both attribute and content using xpath?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, xquery

Xpath `//a[contains(@class, 'storylink')]/@*` will extract all attributes of anchor tags. Anchor tag in my xml doesn't have **title** attribute which usually have content of the link. Is there a way to select **both href and text content in anchor link** with XPATH 1.0 ?

Comment: Add a full example of the source content (a full XML fragment) and the exact expected output.

Comment: @DavidEnnis eg: [http://news.ycombinator.com](http://news.ycombinator.com) I'm trying to extract title along with href.

Comment: Sorry...  I meant in your sample - not for someone to have to fish around on the source of a web page.. Expand your question with example input and expected output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select both `@href` and `text()` in a single XPath selection, you can use the union operator `|`.

With XPath 1.0, this is probably the best you can do:

```
//a[contains(@class, 'storylink')]/@href | //a[contains(@class, 'storylink')]/text()
```

With XPath 2.0 (or higher) you could avoid repeating the anchor selection criteria:

```
//a[contains(@class, 'storylink')]/(@href,text())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select the `a` element itself using `//a[contains(@class, 'storylink')]` and then get the required attributes and/or text content using Javascript methods on the returned element node.

You could indeed select both the attributes and the text using XPath, but if they're all jumbled up in a single query result then it's a hassle separating them again.

Comment: for my use case I'm trying to find a XPath to use with Google Sheets `=ImportXml()` formula that directly populates extracted values to sheet. i.e Title in one column and href in another column.